# cant play video from webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I want to play video from webview using intent but it give some error while start playing.
i use following code.

```
myweb.loadUrl("http://www.clipcanvas.com/a/video-clip-downloads/");

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if(url.endsWith(".mp4")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url),"video/*");
        view.getContext().startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

but after choose player it.following process images.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: why are you using if(url.endsWith(".mp4")) ???

Comment: i also try in real device but it play for 1 or 2 second and then stop.